# SharePoint 2010 Library Tree View

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

What is the best way to create a SharePoint tree view web part for a document library?

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to get the treeview with clientsidecode

Something like this

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
context.load(list,'Include(RootFolder)');
context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    createRoot(list);
},
function (sender, args) {
     console.log('error');
});
```

then you have to make a createRoot function that inserts the html from the library tree when the user clicks. That depends that the tree is not expanded by default.

Answer (score 0):

Elena,

If you are looking for Out of the box way, you can use Grouping to achieve some level of Tree view..

But if you want folder wise structure as a complete Tree-view till n-levels, there is no Out of the box feature available. You will need to create a custom Web Part, already shown here:

[Document Library Tree View Web Part for SharePoint](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37530/Document-Library-Tree-View-Web-Part-for-SharePoint)

Or

[Add a Treeview to a Document LIbrary using SPTreeView and SPHierarchicalDataSource](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/pages/add-a-treeview-to-a-document-library-using-sptreeview-and-sphierarchicaldatasource.aspx)

Comment: I did grouping, but I don't think it is the best way to view the documents in the library.

Comment: Do I need to use Visual Studio for if I ll follow the first link instructions?

Comment: Yes, visual studio to develop a Visual Web Part..